# ios phonegap webview events when no internet connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using a cordova `webview` to load an html file that has a button that triggers shouldStartLoad event on click using js.

All is working fine excepts when no internet connection that when same button is pressed, `shouldStartLoad` event is not fired. I need to intercept that trigger in order to show a native alert but seems that nothing happens, if internet connection is available again, event is also fired again when click.
Console is not showing any info. How to intercept this state on cordova `webview` when no connection?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request 
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is no internet connection and your pressing button to fire some event, check the `UIWebViewDelegate` method called `didFailWithError`:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

     //Check the error type and show the appropriate alert to user.
}
```

and as you are using Phonegap, you can always check internet connection first by using [Connection API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) before firing any load request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        //checkConnection();
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        if(networkState==Connection.NONE)
          return false;
        else
         return true; 
    }
    function loadGoogle() {

      if(checkConnection()){
       // Do your logical stuff here
       window.location="https://google.com";
      }
      else {
        // Handle connection error 
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
    <button onclick="loadGoogle()">Load Google</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: didFailWithError is also not triggered and using html is not a solution too. Assuming that html is properly loaded on webview and have button that fires an event onClick, then I deactivate internet connection on device. Now when click, I must capture any event in order to check internet conn. But interaction state is previous to conn check.